# How to move specific images to a new folder php

Tags: php

I have a folder that contain some images `pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic3.jpg, frame2.jpg. round.jpg`. My question is how to move only `pic*.jpg` images to a new folder without adding the other images `frame*.jpg` and `round.jpg` using php

Comment: [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) & [`rename()`](http://php.net/rename)

Answer (score 1):

Use `php` [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
foreach(glob("/old/pic*.jpg") as $file)
{
    rename($file, "/new/".basename($file));
}
```

Comment: `rename($file, "/new/"+basename($file));` that `+` should be a `.`

Answer (score 0):

```
// search for all the pathnames matching pattern
foreach(glob("/myfolder/pic*.jpg") as $file)
{ 
// check if newfolder exists, if not create it
if(!is_dir('/newfolder') && !file_exists('/newfolder')) {
mkdir('/newfolder', 0755);
}
// new file path
$newfile = '/newfolder/'.basename($file);
// copy file to new location
copy($file, $newfile);
}
```